# My code partially writes list output as data frame columns to csv, but break after that

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I have a dataset with two columns and I want to match the strings in both the column and produce a match percentage in the third column. And then I'd like to take all the three columns in a CSV. Here's my code.

```
    Data: 

    **RoS  FCRA**
    pink pinky 
    rose grass 
    thick thin
```

Code:

```
from fuzzywuzzy import fuzz, process
import pandas as pd
import csv

df = pd.read_excel("/Users/shreyaagarwal/Desktop/fcra test.xlsx")
with open("myfile.csv", "w") as fh:
     writer = csv.writer(fh)
     for i in (df["RoS"]):
        for p in (df["FCRA"]):
            s = p.encode('ascii', 'ignore').decode('ascii')
            match = fuzz.partial_ratio(i,s)
            df["Fuzzymatch"] = match
            writer.writerow([i,s,match])



Desired Output: 
    **RoS  FCRA  Match**
    pink pinky 20
    pink grass 0
    pink thin 0
    rose pinky 0
    rose grass 0
    rose thin 0
```

Comment: And how is your attempt wrong? "Unable" sounds like it physicalny nost the ability to print anything.

Comment: The desired output doesn't look like CSV; do you want that to be tab-delimited?

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be <del>looping over the wrong things and</del> introducing variables you never use. I'm guessing you want something like

```
from fuzzywuzzy import fuzz, process
import pandas as pd
import csv

df = pd.read_excel("test.xlsx")
with open("myfile.csv", "w") as fh:
    writer = csv.writer(fh)
    for i in df["RoS"]:
        for p in df["FCRA"]:
            match = fuzz.partial_ratio(i,p)
            writer.writerow([i,p,match])
```

Here's an attempt at a [MCVE](/help/mcve):

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(
    [['pink', 'pinky'], ['rose', 'grass'], ['thick', 'thin']],
    columns=['RoS', 'FCRA'])
for i in df["RoS"]:
    for p in df["FCRA"]:
        print(i, p)
```

Result:

```
('pink', 'pinky')
('pink', 'grass')
('pink', 'thin')
('rose', 'pinky')
('rose', 'grass')
('rose', 'thin')
('thick', 'pinky')
('thick', 'grass')
('thick', 'thin')
```

Comment: Looks like your code wouldn't match each item in column1 with all the items in column2. I got this Error: '_csv.writer' object has no attribute 'write'. So, I tried, writerows. But, it only takes one argument at a time. And I want to have all three arguments passed at the same time to stack the columns next to each other.

Comment: Oh sorry, fixed the error now, and updated to permute over all the values in the second column for each value in the first, like your code does.

Comment: I have updated my code, thanks to your suggestion. It now loops over just the first item in column1 and matches it with all the items in column 2. But, before getting to the second item in column 1, it breaks.

Comment: "It breaks" does not help solve anything. Post the traceback.

Comment: There's no traceback, because there's no error in the code. In the output, it doesn't  go beyond matching the first item in the first column.

Comment: I added a MCVE. If your dataframe has the same shape as your example, the code should do what you require. If not, please [edit] your question to show how it's different; we don't have access to your Excel file so we can't know what data you are actually attempting to process.